# ERD modeling organization and roles

Tags: database-design, erd

I am trying to model the following scenario:

```
  -I have multiple company bureaus.

  -Each Bureau has multiple offices

  -Each office has multiple divisions

  -Each Bureau has employees that only work at the bureau level (think CEO's,CIO's,etc) and employees that work at the many office level

  -Each office has people who only work at the office level (maybe managers, chief,s etc) and people who work at the many divisions levels

  - Each division has people who work only at the division level (division chiefs, for example) and employees who work on projects

  -  Also, each division has projects that are run by division staff (employees, not the high level divisions chiefs)
```

I want to be able to do the following with the data:

- query the structure of the organization (what divisions are in what office, for example)
- query the various C level people from each division, office, bureau, etc.
- find projects by all levels ( if given a bureau, office, or division get projects associated)
- find people who are working on a given project.  These projects will have multiple roles

What I currently have is this:

[image: ERD]

But I can't get who works at the bureau or office level if they aren't tied to a division.  Any help would be great.

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't getting much attention?  Am I asking something incorrectly or not providing enough info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -Each Bureau has employees that only work at the bureau level (think CEO's,CIO's,etc) and employees that work at the many office level
>
> -Each office has people who only work at the office level (maybe managers, chief,s etc) and people who work at the many divisions levels
>
> -Each division has people who work only at the division level (division chiefs, for example) and employees who work on projects
>
> -Also, each division has projects that are run by division staff (employees, not the high level divisions chiefs)

These rules imply that each employee has a role that requires they work either **only** for a bureau, an office, or a division, **or** requires they work for a given bureau and many offices, or an office and many divisions, or a division, and that only employees who work for a division but are not division staff run projects.  The schema shown however asserts only that employees work for a division in any given role and that any of them can run a project.  Changes are needed to bring the schema into line with rules.

The simplest way to address the business rules is to add tables to associate employees to offices and bureaus in addition to divisions.  Each employee would then be associated to each organization level in which they work.  Employees working only at a bureau, or office, or division would only be associated to that level.  Employees working at a bureau who also work at many offices would be associated to the bureau in that associative table and then also associated to the many offices by that associative table.  Note this approach only addresses where each employee **actually** works and not the **rules** as to which roles can work at which organizational levels.  To address the rules more discovery and modeling is required and is beyond the scope of this answer.

Secondly, the business rules imply that an employee has a single role - say a CIO or office manager or division chief - and not a role per associated location.  The schema can be brought into agreement with this rule, if correct, by making the role table a parent of the employee table such that each employee is assigned a single role.  Now this implication may or may not be true.  Perhaps an employee can have only a single role at a moment in time, but many over time.  In this case temporal columns are also required.  Perhaps an employee really can have many roles at the same time at different organization levels, in which case the role would **not** be determined by the employee.  Ultimately, more clarity is needed on the full scope of the business rules by having the subject matter expert review the model and determine if it represents accurately the rules by which they operate.  It is vital to fully understand and document the functional dependencies and natural keys in order to arrive at the correct logical design.  Right now the diagram does not show any natural keys so even if the functional dependencies were presented it would not be possible to determine if the logical design is in agreement with them.  Finally, the diagram shows that each parent entity is optional and I doubt that is really the case.  A business SME can determine under what circumstances the parent occurrence is optional, and for each of those circumstances more work is needed to determine **why** the parent occurrence is optional and resolve it so it is no longer optional.

I hope these points help in improving the design to meet all the informational objectives.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Just to clarify, each employee would only have one position.  But, at the division level, an employee can manage multiple projects.  And this application isn't meant to track employees over time.  Just report on the current state of employee and projects.  I assume I would keep the associations between Bureau->office->division as well as add associations to employees?

Comment: Since each employee has only one position and we don't track changes to that over time, the role table should be a parent of the employee table not the division employee roles table.  Absolutely keep the bureau to office to division tables as this matches your business rules.  You are correct as you just need to now add the associations of each to employees.